# .on() doesn't work on appended element(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm appending a row in a table and then upon clicking a button I want to remove that row.
However I can't do it in a way that seems natural, like:

```
$(".usun").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

where `.usun` is a class of buttons that remove a row in a table. Of course this fragment of code is inside of `$(document).ready(...`. What seems to work for me is this:

```
$(this).on("click", ".usun", function(){ 
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

and I don't understand why. Could someone explain me this?

Comment: Read http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: When you do `$(".usun").on(`, you are binding to all `".usun"` elements that exist at that given point. `$(this).on("click", ".usun"` actually binds the event to `this`, and just checks to see if you clicked on a `".usun"`.

Comment: learn about `closest("tr")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several method signatures available for `.on()` which you can read about [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Your first syntax (`$(".usun").on(`) is, just one time, attaching click handlers to each individual `.usun` element. If more are added later, they don't have click handlers.

The second syntax (`$(this).on("click", ".usun", function()...`) attaches a *single* listener to the `document`, saying "any time a `.usun` inside me is clicked, do something". This covers a case where more matching elements are added after `$(document).ready` is fired.

Comment: attaches **multible** click handlers: one to each `.usun` element.... attaches a **single** click handler to `document`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because that specific `.usun` does not exist yet when you are registering the event.
You need to register the event to its parent element (prefereably the table id) like so:

```
$('#yourtableid').on("click", ".usun", function(){ //if table id does not exist, you can use $('body') instead
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

This will make sure that you are attaching the events even to 'unborn' elements.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So you're aware of this... your question is related to **live** and **non-live lists** (collections) in javascript;

review the following Javascript,

```
var queryStatic = document.querySelectorAll(".usun"); //non-live | static list
var queryLive = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); //live list
```

queryStatic will return a NodeList that statically references the nodes that satistifed the condition of the query.

If you were to alter/modify the properties/fields/members of a node or it's element that is referenced by this NodeList outside of using the queryStatic, it would be represented in the queryStatic instance;

you cannot, however, add a new element/node to the DOM that ***would have*** satisfied the query and expect it to be in that NodeList.

queryList (an HTML Collection), however, will represent both aspects. It is a live list.

The point is, the underline concept has little to nothing to do with method signatures.

### Edit

However, in the case of jQuery's `.on()` method; there is support for attaching the listener to a parent element (like `Document`) and specifying an additional query criteria.

Comment: On second review, although this concept is related, it's not actually the appropriate answer to what you're asking.. as @Alex pointed out, the event using `$(this)` is being attached to the `document`.. not a collection of Html Elements or a NodeList.